# How to check if an element has a specific position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, performance, css

I'm trying to check the position of the 'car' so if it's top:200px I want to add a property to the 'phone'. The idea is when you scroll down, the car is moving and when the car is within the scope of the phone, the phone should flash.

I'm giving an If statement but something is broken and I cannot figure out what exactly. Someone to help?

```js
$(window).scroll(function () { 
    //You've scrolled this much:
    var newSize = $(window).scrollTop()/20;
    var srotate = "translateY(" + newSize + "px)";
    $('.car').css({top:newSize,"-moz-transform" : srotate, "-webkit-transform" : srotate});
    
  if($('.car').css('top') == '195px') {
      $('.phone').css('box-shadow', '1px', '1px', '17px', '4px', '#42ab9e');
    }
});
```

```css
.he{
  height:4000px;
  overflow-x: hidden;  
}
.car{
  right:20px;
  position:fixed;
  margin-top:20px;
  display:block;
  z-index:0;
}
.car  img {
      width: 40px;
  }
.phone {
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1950px;
  z-index:1;
  padding-right: 6px;
  right:0px;
}
.phone img {
    width:67px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="he container"></div>
<div class="car">
   <img src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/nai005qun3o0h9r81e0ndpvrh6_car.png" alt="car">
</div>
<div class="phone">
  <img src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/nai005qun3o0h9r81e0ndpvrh6_phone.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To check the specific position of an element, the best way is to use HTML 5 Canvas. With the use of Kinetic-js you can draw objects on canvas as well as when the object is being dragged we can get the co-ordinates.
The overall idea is that using kinetic js you can get the coordinates and then you can achieve whatever you like.
I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue can easily be solved by getting the `car`'s distance from the top of the screen: (also, your jquery adding css is broken)

```
if($('.car').offset().top >= 195) {
    $('.phone').css('box-shadow', '1px 1px 17px 4px #42ab9e');
}
```

Afterwards you can use this to add a class to your phone or anything else.
Checking the top of the `car` element is not a very useful thing. You check the offset from the top of the screen and not in px, because the result is just a float. Also, check if car is equal or higher, because if you only check for equal it might never happen.

Open up the console in my edited example and see the results:
https://jsfiddle.net/L2pf7cmu/